# Mobile Input Not Working Unity 3d 2017

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, cross-platform

greetings fellow programmers and game devs.

I am kind of new to Unity3D. I have the latest beta build of 2017 Personal.

I have a bit of a problem. I have a first person controller prefab and a dual touch control and an event system, yet when I test the game on my iPhone 5s, I can look around but as soon as I am done panning by swiping the camera resets to the place I was looking previously and I am unable to move forward or back.

Now, I also tried not having the dual touch control and it does the same thing. 
Also, I checked input and the axis is set to both Horizontal and Vertical and the other is Mouse X and Mouse Y. I also tried dragging two mobile joy sticks and assigning them Mouse X and Mouse Y and the other joystick Horizontal and Vertical.

Any help would be appreciated. I also want to note that I had another project that worked with just dragging and dropping the dual touch controls on to the hierarchy and even though the settings are the same for the FPSController and the Camera and the Controls it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi, i think you need to provide some details, and try to narrow you problem, you can show your code and points where is the issue. i believe more people will try to help.

Comment: I know that when you drag and drop dual touch controls prefab with a first person controller prefab with an event system component and with mobile input enabled that touch controls are supposed to work out of the box without coding. So there is no code.